# Render PDF into an image (self-contained, no external command line dependencies) (to use on AWS Lambda)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pdf, aws-lambda, pdf2image

I need a simple python library to convert PDF to image (render the PDF as is), but after hours of searching, I keep hitting the same wall, I find libraries like `pdf2image` python library (and many similar ones), which depend on external applications or wrap command-line tools.

Although there are workarounds to allow using these libraries in serverless settings, they all would complicate our deployment and require creating the likes of `Execution Environments` or extra lambda layers, which will eat up from the small allowed lambda size.

Is there a self-contained, independent mechanism (not dependent on command-line tools) to allow achieving this (seemingly simple) task?

Also, I am wondering, is there a reason (licensing or patents) for the scarcity of tools that deal with PDFs (they are mostly commercial or under strict AGPL licenses)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software is a good resource

Comment: QPDF seems to be a reasonable library (there is an established Pythonic wrapper not based on command line crap), but can't find any way to convert/render PDF to images :(

Comment: Oh, didn't know they are based on Ghostscript, this is brutal, all seem to use the same stuff in the background, how could they offer it as Apache then? really strange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236481/discussion-between-sawan-and-k-j).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said "Ended up using pdf2image"

[pdf2image (MIT)](https://pypi.org/project/pdf2image/). A python (3.6+) module that wraps pdftoppm (GPL?) and pdftocairo (GPL?) to convert PDF to a PIL Image object.

Generally [Poppler (GPL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_(software)) spinoffs from Open Source [Xpdf (GPL)](http://www.xpdfreader.com/about.html) which has

- pdftopng:
- pdftoppm:
- pdfimages:

and a 3rd party pdftotiff

Comment: We ended up not using this because of licensing limitations, and using a SaaS service until we figure out a library, a bit annoying tbh!

Comment: The use case is so small, not worth losing sleep over it for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert PDF's to images without external dependencies using PyMuPDF. I use it for Azure functions.

Install with `pip install PyMuPDF`

In your python file:

```
import fitz
pdfDoc = fitz.open(filepath)
img = pdfDoc[0].get_pixmap(matrix=fitz.Matrix(2,2))
bytesimg = img.tobytes()
```

This takes the first page of the PDF and converts it to an image, the matrix is for the resolution.

You can also open a stream instead of a file on disk:

```
pdfDoc = fitz.open(stream = pdfstream, filetype="pdf")
```